# Add a filter of import (filter_glob) for specific filenames (foo.dat;me.dat and nothing else) in file browser

Tags: interface, file-browser

My question is complete enough, here is my current code but it has a breach, I want to patch it and make it only shows files that are exactly "main.dat", "assetlookup.dat" and "debug.dat"
Thanks :)

```py
    filename_ext = ".dat"
    filter_glob: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        default="main.dat;assetlookup.dat;debug.dat",
        options={"HIDDEN"}
    )
```

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/T81208

Comment: Hmmm... I checked and it does not answer. It just reports a bug which has no valid answer

Comment: According to the bug report, it broke in 2.90 and has not been fixed yet.

Comment: It's annoying, I have to proceed mandatorily like this then: *main.dat;*assetlookup.dat;*debug.dat